# problem in running rosserial on raspberry

Tags: rosserial, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed rosserial on raspberry pi according to the instructions given in the following link 
http://wiki.jigsawrenaissance.org/ROS_on_RaspberryPi 
On running  *roslaunch rosserial_server serial.launch port:=/dev/ttyACM0*  following is showing ....

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ roslaunch rosserial_server serial.launch port:=/dev/ttyACM0
... logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/f8109b02-82a0-11e4-83ef-b827eb8371f7/roslaunch-raspberrypi-4607.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://raspberrypi:55941/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosserial_server/port
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    rosserial_message_info (rosserial_python/message_info_service.py)
    rosserial_server (rosserial_server/serial_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rosserial_server-1]: started with pid [4653]
process[rosserial_message_info-2]: started with pid [4683]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/message_info_service.py", line 46, in <module>
    from rosserial_python import load_message
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 50, in <module>
    import diagnostic_msgs.msg
ImportError: No module named diagnostic_msgs.msg
[rosserial_message_info-2] process has died [pid 4683, exit code 1, cmd /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/message_info_service.py __name:=rosserial_message_info __log:=/home/pi/.ros/log/f8109b02-82a0-11e4-83ef-b827eb8371f7/rosserial_message_info-2.log].
log file: /home/pi/.ros/log/f8109b02-82a0-11e4-83ef-b827eb8371f7/rosserial_message_info-2*.log
```

What is the error? Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199418/problem-in-running-rosserial-on-raspberry/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm no `rosserial` wizard, but I would say this is the error:

```
ImportError: No module named diagnostic_msgs.msg
```

Have you got that package installed?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-12-14**:
Right ..whole common_msgs stack was not installed . Now it is running well ..Thanks .

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-05-03**:
how did you go about installing the stack and where exactly did you install it? Please help!

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2015-05-05**:
@miguel ..I think i downloaded the source and build it ....Here is the link of source code of diagnostic and other messages. https://github.com/ros/common_msgs

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-05-05**:
Thank you, I figured it out. I was being silly just needed to clone it into rosserial in my workspace and build it. Thanks for the reply though!